# Fitting a linear regression model in R with confounding variables

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I have a dataset called `datamoth` where `survival` is the response variable and `treatment` is a variable that can be considered both categorical and quantitative. The dataset looks like follows:

```
survival <- c(17,22,26,20,11,14,37,26,24,11,11,16,8,5,12,3,5,4,14,8,4,6,3,3,10,13,5,7,3,3)
treatment <- c(3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,12,12,12,12,12,12,21,21,21,21,21,21)
days <- c(3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,12,12,12,12,12,12,21,21,21,21,21,21)

datamoth <- data.frame(survival, treatment)
```

So, I can fit a linear regression model considering treatment as categorical, like this:

```
lmod<-lm(survival ~ factor(treatment), datamoth)
```

My question is how to fit a linear regression model with treatment as categorical variable but also considering treatment as a quantitative confounding variable.
I have figured out something like this:

```
model <- lm(survival ~ factor(treatment) + factor(treatment)*days, data = datamoth)
summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = survival ~ factor(treatment) + factor(treatment) * 
    days, data = datamoth)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-9.833 -3.333 -1.167  3.167 16.167 

Coefficients: (5 not defined because of singularities)
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                18.333      2.435   7.530 6.96e-08 ***
factor(treatment)6          2.500      3.443   0.726  0.47454    
factor(treatment)9        -12.167      3.443  -3.534  0.00162 ** 
factor(treatment)12       -12.000      3.443  -3.485  0.00183 ** 
factor(treatment)21       -11.500      3.443  -3.340  0.00263 ** 
days                           NA         NA      NA       NA    
factor(treatment)6:days        NA         NA      NA       NA    
factor(treatment)9:days        NA         NA      NA       NA    
factor(treatment)12:days       NA         NA      NA       NA    
factor(treatment)21:days       NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 5.964 on 25 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5869,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5208 
F-statistic: 8.879 on 4 and 25 DF,  p-value: 0.0001324
```

But obviously this code is not working because these two variables are collinear.
Does anyone to know how to fix it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no column `days` in your dataset. 2) it would be better to define `treatment <- factor(treatment)` once and for all instead of multiple times.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the variable days in the days, so, after including it and defining treatment as factor, it would look like this

Comment: survival<-matrix(c(17,22,26,20,11,14,37,26,24,11,11,16,8,5,12,3,5,4,14,8,4,6,3,3,10,13,5,7,3,3), ncol=1, nrow=30)
treatment<-matrix(c(3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,12,12,12,12,12,12,21,21,21,21,21,21), nrow=30,ncol=1)
treatment <- factor(treatment, labels = c("A", "B","C","D","E"))
days<-matrix(c(3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,12,12,12,12,12,12,21,21,21,21,21,21), nrow=30,ncol=1)
datamoth<-data.frame(survival, treatment, days)

Comment: However, it is still not working as expected, the variables (treatment and days) continue to be perfectly collinear.

Comment: `day` and `treatment` are the same variable. What you're trying to do is similar to adding `treatment` to the model twice (adds no additional info to the model). I don't think there is a solution other than leaving one of the two variables out of the model (i.e. treat the variable either as numeric or as a factor)

Comment: Seems like a statistical question, not a programming one. But if your data has variables that are perfectly collinear, I'm not sure what you expect the model to do to change that.